# Personality Quiz with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I am quite new to Javascript and I have to make a personality quiz. I need the quiz to be just Javascript, no jQuery. I need to make each answer option clickable, and only show one question at a time. As well as finding a way to store each answer to display a result. I'm just not sure where to start with this and I've been having a bit of trouble. This may seem silly, but I'd really like some help in seeing where I've gone wrong and how I can fix it. Below is what I've done so far with html, css and javascript. Thanks in advance

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
startButton.addEventListener("click", startClick);

function startClick() {

    var intro = document.getElementById("intro");
    intro.style.display = "none";
    startButton.style.display = "none";

    var question1 = document.getElementById("question1");
    question1.style.display = "block";

}

var answerButton = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
answerButton[0].addEventListener("click", answerClick);
console.dir(answerButton);

function answerClick(eventObject) {
    var eventClick = eventObject.target;

var question = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
    
for(i= 0; i < question.length; i ++); {
  question[i].style.display = "block";
    
}
}
```

```css
@charset"UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.5;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/*above is Eric Meyer CSS reset*/
 #titleimage {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: .5%;
    padding-bottom: .5%;
}
#titleimage img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.question, #results {
    display: none;
}

p {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 1em;
}
h3 {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 150;
    text-align:center;
}
h2 {
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:200;
    text-align:center;
}
.button {
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align:center;
}
.button:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.question li {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ADDEF4;
}
.question li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#results img {
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="titleimage">
        <img src="Parks-and-rec.jpg" alt="Parks and Rec Banner">
    </div>
    <div id="intro">
         <h2>Take the quiz to see which Parks and Rec character is most like you!</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="startButton" class="button">
         <h3>Let's get started!</h3>

    </div>
    <div id="question1" class="question">
        <p>What is your favourite food?</p>
        <ul id="answers1">
            <li>Breakfast Food</li>
            <li>Waffles</li>
            <li>Calzones</li>
            <li>Vegan Superfoods</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="question2" class="question">
        <p>What do you enjoy doing in your spare time?</p>
        <ul id="answers2">
            <li>Woodwork in solitary</li>
            <li>Work!</li>
            <li>Make stop motion 'movies'</li>
            <li>Run!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="question3" class="question">
        <p>What would you do on "treat yo'self" day?</p>
        <ul id="answers3">
            <li>Buy a Batman suit and be Batman</li>
            <li>Go to my lakehouse by myself</li>
            <li>Treat myself to waffles and friends</li>
            <li>Run! Or maybe some yoga</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="question4" class="question">
        <p>What are you likely to be doing on a Friday night?</p>
        <ul id="answers4">
            <li>Cooking vegan hamburgers</li>
            <li>Being alone, maybe with some Scotch</li>
            <li>Still working or hanging out with my bestie</li>
            <li>Watching Game of Thrones</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="question5" class ="question" >
        <p>What do you find funny?</p>
        <ul id="answers5">
            <li>Accounting puns</li>
            <li>The Government</li>
            <li>Myself</li>
            <li>You can laugh at anything!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
        <div id="Leslie" class="result">
            <p>You get Leslie Knope!</p>
            <img src="leslie.jpg" alt="Leslie Knope giving two thumbs up!">
        </div>
        <div id="Ron" class="result">
            <p>You got Ron Swanson!</p>
            <img src="ron.png" alt="Ron Swanson smiling">
        </div>
        <div id="Ben" class="result">
            <p>You got Ben Wyatt!</p>
            <img src="ben.png" alt="Ben Wyatt">
        </div>
        <div id="Chris" class="result">
            <p>You got Chirs Traeger!</p>
            <img src="chris.png" alt="Chris Traeger saying good job">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript" src="quiz.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, HTML has **[well established form control elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms)**, you should have a look at them first. Otherwise, I don't quite understand what the problem is, try to describe it better. Throwing all your code at us and expecting us to read thhrough it won't work well for you.

Comment: Sorry about my question, I can see how it's not all that helpful.  At the moment I'm having trouble displaying the next question after an answer is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you have a problem with, but this might help.

A possible route would be to have your questions and answers in an object, kind of like

```
var quizz = [ 
{ 
question: 'what is your favourite foode?',
answers : { 
        'breakfast': 'value that helps you calculate', 
        'calzone': 'value that helps you calculate'
     }
}, 
{ 
question: 'other question?',
answers : { 
           'answer 1': 'value that helps you calculate', 
           'answer 2': 'value that helps you calculate'
    }
}
];
```

then maybe have an object that handles your answers. It will have some function that checks the question, and updates the result with your answer's value.

That should work and help you figure it out.

As for getting your answers, make sure to use the html form elements properly, get their values and test against your question. you can change the "pagE" simply by changing the question wrapper, or rendering it from the object with questions (rendering current+1 from the quizz array).

Excuse the formatting :P. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in JavaScript:

```
for(i= 0; i < question.length; i ++)/**** ; ****/ {
  question[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

PS. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, use AngularJS :)